# The question about the support of Fourier transform of $|f|^p$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose $f$ is a smooth function with $\mathbb{supp}{(\mathcal{F}{f})} \subset B(0,1)$. In addition, assume $f$ is non-negative.

We can observe that the function $|f|^2$ has a nice property :
$$\mathbb{supp{(\mathcal{F}(|f|^2))}}=\mathbb{supp{(\mathcal{F}(f)\ast\mathcal{F}(f)})} \subset B(0,2)$$
Let $1 < p < 2$. Does there exist a constant $C$ independent of $p$ such that
$$\mathbb{supp(\mathcal{F}(|f|^p))} \subset B(0,C)$$
for all $f$ satisfying the above conditions? This is not homework or exercise in some book but my pure question.

What I did :

Let $p$ be a rational number. Put $p=\frac{n}{m}$, $n$, $m$ $\in \mathbb{N}$. First, we have
$$\mathbb{supp{(\mathcal{F}(|f|^n))}} \subset B(0,n)$$
Put $g(x)=|f(x)|^{\frac{n}{m}}$. Then 
$$\mathcal{F}(g) \; \ast \; ... \; \ast \; \mathcal{F}(g) (m-times) = \mathcal{F}(|f|^n)$$
If $\mathcal{F}(g)$ is always non-negative, then
$$\mathcal{F}(g) \subset B(0,\frac{n}{m})$$
But in general we cannot deduce that because $\mathcal{F}g$ can be negative. I don't believe that my claim is correct, but finding counterexample is extremely hard. Any comments or hints are welcomed.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but is there even a positive function with Fourier support in the unit ball?  Even if the answer is no, the question you ask is still interesting.

Comment: @felipeh Take any function $g$ such that $\mathbb{supp{g}} \subset B(0,1/2)$. Now,  put $\mathcal{F}(f)=g \ast g$. Then by Fourier inversion formula, $f$ is non-negative, but it has support condition in the frequency region.

Comment: @felipeh Oh, the word 'positive' should be adjusted to 'non-negative'. Thanks.

Comment: Oh of course, thanks.  Nice construction.